# Resolving TypeError: NoneType object is not iterable when iterating through rasters in list compiled by arcpy.ListRasters()?

Tags: arcpy

[image]

From what I can gather is that arcpy.ListRasters("*.TIF*") is not storing the required rasters in "rasters". Since raster is empty, the program cannot iterate over rasters in "rasters". The error is in line 16 which is for raster in rasters:.

Comment: You have a * after tif, remove that.

Comment: Make sure the workspace (F:\raster_test) actually exists. If you run this code on a directory that doesn't exist you'll get the NoneType error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code snippet and your error messages as *text* not as images.  This makes your code and errors searchable, and also makes it easier for potential answerers to copy/paste your code for their own testing

Comment: @Hornbydd I believe the extra * will allow `.TIFF` files to be included as well as `.TIF`

Comment: @Hornbydd Removing the extra * didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Dan Jurgella The workspace (F:\raster_test) actually exists.

Comment: @Midavalo I will do that next time.\\\\

Comment: This time would be better than next time - There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Your `arcpy.env.workspace` path - `F:\raster_test` - probably doesn't exist or arcpy has no access to it.  The `arcpy.ListRasters()` will return an empty list `[]` if no rasters are found, but will return `None` if the path isn't found:

Path does exist:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp"  # Does Exist
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif)
print rasters
```

Will output:

```
[]
```

Path does **not** exist:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp2"  # Does NOT Exist
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif)
print rasters
```

Will output:

```
None
```

Answer (score 3):

...also, backing up closer toward the beginning of the code is this faulty line (\r is an escape sequence in Python):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\raster_test"  # Does NOT Exist
```

Provided F:\raster_test is a valid path (and contains rasters), then this should work fine:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\raster_test" # Does Exist
```

See Python doc section on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings).

Comment: +1 @Sujai This is a classic python gotcha (on Windows at least). "\r" is the escape sequence for a carriage return.  A more up to date (though the actual escape seqs haven't changed) is https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings

Comment: You're right, Luke....link in answer updated to the newer link.  Lots of other good stuff on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is causing your `NoneType` error, `arcpy.ListRasters()` would return an empty list and never a `NoneType` if there were no rasters found.  Give this a shot:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy.sa import ExtractByMask

out_dir = r'F:\clipped_images'
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\raster\test'
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

mask = r'F:\shapefile\Export_Output.shp'

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif'):
    output_raster = os.path.join(out_dir, os.path.splitext(raster)[0] + '_clip.tif')
    ExtractByMask(raster, mask, output_raster)

arcpy.CheckInExtension('Spatial')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the various `List` functions (`ListTables`, `ListFeatureclasses`, etc) always return `None` if there are no matched types in the given workspace. Do a quick `if` logic test for your list variable.

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters ("*.TIF")
if rasters:
    your code here
```